# Парсинг из html

Tags: javascript

Как можно спарсить текст из date

```
<block>
<date>27.08.2014</date>
</block>
```

Comment: это у Вас отдельно загружаемый xml, или прямо в тексте страницы html?

Comment: Получаю txt фаил   через $.get() в котором это содержится

Comment: точно не проще json сделать ? не очень кошерно, но можно сделать как-то так `var date=$(data).find('date').text();`

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var w = "<block>
                  <date>27.08.2014</date>
              </block>";
     alert(w.substr(w.indexOf("<date>") + 6), w.indexOf("</date>") - w.indexOf("<date>") - 6));
<script>
```

Comment: За такую попытку помочь -
За попытку +
За то что повеселили + 
И того 1 +. Неплохо...

Comment: А что не понравилось?

Comment: >А что не понравилось?

ну наверное потому что это слишком уж наивная реализация что ли. а если у вас будет xml с другими узлами? С другим числом узлов, с другими названиями, с другой вложенностью? Вы так же будете писать для каждого нового случая кучу **indexOf**? Это несерьезно

Comment: Тут телепатов нет. Не кто не знает, что у вас там. Вы где то упомянули что это XML?

Тогда так:
var w = "<block><date>27.08.2014</date></block>";

alert(w.match(/<date>[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.20[0-9]{2}<\/date>/)[0].substr(6, 10));

Каков вопрос - таков ответ.

Comment: В таком случае у вас не будет проблем с другой вложенностью